# How to use jquery in php file?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am currently creating a table with php and data from a mysql db...

So I need to use Jquery in the table....

How can I do this? Im guessing I have to import the library somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean an HTML table or do you mean a MySQL table?

Comment: Try one of the numerous jquery tutorials. This question seems to be a request for some very basic information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place this somewhere in the HTML Header area of your PHP file:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP and JQuery have nothing to do with each other. PHP generates HTML and JS that can contain JQuery. You embed JQuery as you would in a normal HTML page.